# Can I backup my purchased android app

Tags: backup

I need this information because,  if my data gets lost because of some reason I need to reinstall all my apps, but what about those which I've purchased.  Is it necessary to purchase those purchased apps again or else their is a way for backup.

Comment: Once purchased you can download them in any device, no need to purchase them again.

Comment: As @xangua said, you can install a purchased app on any device. Just a couple of notes though. You need to log in with the same Google account you made the purchase with, and there is a limit to how many devices you can install to simultaneously. I don't know the exact limit, but if you hit it, you can uninstall from a device you no longer use and then install it on another device.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup any app you like, even purchased ones.
For your purchased apps: Make sure to log in to the Google Account you purchased it with. Else you might get *"unlicensed"* errors.

Answer (score 0):

Every app you download/buy remain attached to the Google account you used to download/buy them. Even after wiping your phone, you can download your purchased apps from `Play Store -> My Apps`. Or just search for the app and download it.

Comment: Simply downloading might cause some apps to have their `Installed by:` value to be empty and ask for a reinstallation via the Play Store, so be cautious when "just downloading".